# Conditionally Alter link in button in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am trying to figure out a simple way to swap a link in a button in angular js, I have properties available in the scope that I can use, but I am not sure how to implement. The link I am trying to alter is in the 'onClick' attribute in the button. Thanks again in advance, here is my code:

```
<div class="instructions-button">
      <button
      type="button"
      class="halo-modal-action-button external-instructions"
      onClick="window.open('https://mysite/foo');"
      window="new"
      ng-disabled=""
      ng-click=""
      data-bs-enabled=""
      >Instructions</button>
    </div>
```

I am trying to make a simple conditional to show either:

```
'mysite/foo || mysite/bar'
```

but am not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `onClick` event on the button, although it might feel weird to you, since you are coming from vanilla JS, you should use `ng-click`.

```
<button
      class="halo-modal-action-button external-instructions"
      ng-disabled=""
      ng-click="openWindow()"
      data-bs-enabled=""
      >Instructions</button>
```

and inside controller

```
$scope.openWindow = function(){
    if ( condition ) {
        open('http:foo.bar')
    } else {
        open('http:bar.foo')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two simple ways to do this.

1) Two buttons and show one conditionally with `ng-show`.

```
<button ... ng-show="conditionShowFooTrue" >
<button ... ng-show="conditionShowBarTrue" >
```

2) Use `ng-click` to call a scope function to conditionally sets the url as the other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using routes, you can just use `ng-click` like @Akxe said, and with the `$location` service in your controller, do:

```
$scope.changeLocation = function(){
  if(condition)
  {
    $location.path('/foo');
  } else
  {
    $location.path('/bar');
  }
};
```

I think that would be the Angular way to do this.

Comment: He wanted to open it in different window ;)